# Relative error from truncation error in Taylor series expansion

Tags: truncation-error

Given the function $f(x)=\sin x$, please expand it about $x=0$ using Taylor series and truncate the series to $n=6$ terms then find the relative error at $x=\pi/4$ due to truncation found?

Comment: By relative error, do you mean simply dividing the remainder error $|R_6(\pi/4)|$ by the total estimated value? One issue is that we don't know the actual error (o/w we'd just correct our estimate an avoid a lot of work).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.